# Saving image of maze

Tags: c++, sfml

I created a maze generator using sfml and cpp. Once the program is run it creates a maze saves its specs in the format of txt file and then proceed to save a image. Everything works fine, but if i increase the size of the grid or decrease the size of cell dimensions some part of the maze is not saved in the image.

What i see on the screen [dont worry about the not responding part]
[image]

vs what is saved
[image]

If you want to see the source code you can find it on my github:[Github Link](https://github.com/irrevocablesake/website-code/blob/master/Maze%20Generator/ep3/main.cpp)

And if you want a walkthrough of the working of the code, you can read it on my blog:[Blog link](https://irrevocablesake.github.io/series/challenges/Maze%20Generator/index.html)

Note for Mode: My blog is not monetized as of the timing and i am just treating it as a fun archive for projects and challenges.

```
if(once)
        {
            cout<<"maze done!!";

            ofstream output("maze.txt");

            output<<rows<<" "<<cols<<" "<<cellDimensions<<endl;

            for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
                {
                    for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
                    {
                        output<<grid[i][j].wall[k]<<" ";
                    }
                    output<<endl;
                }
            }

            // std::chrono::milliseconds timespan(60000);
            // std::this_thread::sleep_for(timespan); 

            sf::Vector2u windowSize = window.getSize();
            sf::Texture texture;
            texture.create(windowSize.x, windowSize.y);
            texture.update(window);

            sf::Image screenshot = texture.copyToImage();
            screenshot.saveToFile("sc.png");    
            once=0;
        }
```

I feel like the last few statements where i try to save the image are the problem.

Thanks You!

Comment: @drescherjm is it okay?

Comment: Post a [mcve]  / [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) please.